# Keyboard "automatic" double key strokes

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I have a mechanical keyboard (Tt eSPORTS Poseidon Z, Cherry MX Blue switches) for a couple of years and it has recently started double "tapping" some of my characters. For example, when typing "t", it would often type "tt" and so on. It seems to be fairly usual problem with this keyboard.

Do you know of any solution to this problem? A temporary software solution would be fine. For example a software or a Windows feature (I am on Windows 10) that would ignore any double tapped characters if the same second tapped character is below a certain time limit (e.g. 25 ms).

I have tried cleaning the keyboard. I would prefer to not to throw away my keyboard yet.

Answer (score 1):

Strip & clean would be the obvious first fix.

- Get a can of contact cleaner.
- Disconnect from power, remove any batteries.
- Disassemble as far as possible without getting right down to individual keys - you can usually get in without having to strip the keys off.
- Spray thoroughly, allow to dry completely - allow lots more time than you think, evaporation can take a long time from very tightly-enclosed spaces & it will behave very badly if used whilst still wet.

Comment: I have tried cleaning it but I might just give it another go. Unfortunately it seems more like a HW/SW issue.

Comment: Then you ought to have included what you had already tried in your question & what the results were - it saves people wasting time repeating suggestions :/

Comment: Edited. Thank you for your suggestion and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Welcome - I'm assuming your 'cleaning' did include a can of contact cleaner, not just a brush & a damp cloth...

Comment: Silly question maybe but do you have dampening rings installed on your key caps?